# Mongodb failure (Result: core dump)

Tags: mongodb, coredump

I'm having a problem with my mongodb and for some time I have searching for a solution and can't find anyone! So will need some help, tell me: have you ever seen this problem?
[image]

Comment: Have any files been deleted (manually or otherwise) from the dbpath, or any of its subdirectories?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem. I'm using linux mint and folow the wrong instlalation, the installation of Ubuntu instead of debian. The problem was solved!